# Creative Commons and Including Excerpts of my Writing

Tags: discussion

I know that [writers are not lawyers](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/970/you-really-should-be-asking-a-lawyer-rather-than-a-group-of-writers), but perhaps some thought has already been given collectively to this specific question.

Content is posted to Stack Exchange under the [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license.

Are there any known copyright / legal pitfalls when it comes to posting sort excerpts of my own writing from a larger work that I hope to sell one day?